# When using slide to delete in UITableView, the last cell is removed, not the deleted one

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cells, data coming from a Parse API call.  I'm using

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`

to get the indexPath of the cell to delete.  I call the Parse delete method on that cell's object, then after that completes I reloadData in the tableview.  But instead of deleting the selected cell, it removes the last cell in the table.  I've tried using `beginUpdates` instead, not working.  I have even nil'ed out the arrays that I use as the datasource, still removes the last cell.  Now, if I delete the cell by swiping, then close the app and come back in, the correct cell has been deleted.

Anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Can you post some code about deleting?

Comment: are you sure you are using same array?

Comment: i agree with @Paruru please post the code where you actually delete the table view cell...

Comment: did you delete the array element which the index of array is same as the index of table view cell?